# How to call an http://addr?param... get per jquery an parse returned params?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I call an http: get/ajax from jquery and parse returns tokens?

```
http://localhost/getstuff?id=2  // end point is from asp.net mvc4 web api
```

Output:

> ```
> <StuffList>    
>    <Stuff id="2" stuff="thestuff"/>
> </StuffList>
> ```

Comment: Try looking into http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method. So assuming that the server correctly set the response Content-Type header to `text/xml` and sent the XML you have shown in your question, jQuery will automatically build an XML document that you could manipulate:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/values',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
        // result is the XML, you could do any selectors on it
        // for example var stuff = $('Stuff[id=2]', result);

        var stuff = $('Stuff', result);
        var id = stuff.attr('id');
        var someStuff = stuff.attr('stuff');

        alert(id);
        alert(someStuff);
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thx!  QQ: it looks like the response is set to text/javascript...how can I specify that in the header, dataType: 'text/xml'?